# What causes a NullPointerException when a SharedSparkContext (sc) is used outside a test function in FunSuite?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scalatest

The following scala code works fine, and the test runs:

```
import org.scalatest._
import com.holdenkarau.spark.testing._

class DummyTest extends FunSuite with SharedSparkContext {
   test("shared context only works inside test functions.") {
     val myRDD = sc.parallelize(List(1,2,3,4))
   }
}
```

However, the following scala code results in a java.lang.NullPointerException on the line sc.parallelize:

```
import org.scalatest._
import com.holdenkarau.spark.testing._

class DummyTest extends FunSuite with SharedSparkContext {
   val myRDD = sc.parallelize(List(1,2,3,4))
   test("shared context only works inside test functions.") {
      assert(true)
   }
}
```

What causes the NullPointerException when the SparkContext is used outside of the test function?

Comment: where is sc declared?

Comment: You get sc as a field of SharedSparkContext.  E.g. https://github.com/zezutom/spark-by-example/blob/master/src/test/scala/basic/WordCountTest.scala

Comment: beforeAll in SharedSparkContext is responsible to initialize sc which is not happening. Make sure beforeAll method in super class is executed first.

Comment: Can spark unit testing be executed on yarn-client cluster mode?

Comment: When I tried executing the below code in Cluster mode, Spark Context is not getting initialized due to which the job fails with NullPointerException. 
The control is not flowing into the test block as we cannot see the println output.
class mtTest extends FunSuite with SharedSparkContext {
  `test("test array len") 
  {
 println("test1")
    val arr1 = Array[String]("t1")
    val myrdd = sc.parallelize(List(1, 2, 3, 4))
    assert(myrdd.count === 1)
  } 
  test("test array cnt") 
  {
 println("test2")
    val arr1 = Array[String]("t2")
    assert(arr1.count === 1)
  } 
}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The SparkContext is declared within SharedSparkContext but not initialized as part of that trait's initialization. Rather it is initialized in the trait's `beforeAll()` method, which is called by the test framework after the suite has been fully instantiated. Source is here: https://github.com/holdenk/spark-testing-base/blob/master/src/main/pre-2.0/scala/com/holdenkarau/spark/testing/SharedSparkContext.scala. If you use it while initializing your class, `beforeAll()` has not yet been called, so it is still null.

So to summarize, the order is:

1. Super-class initialization (code just in the trait body)
2. Sub-class initialization (code just in your class's body)
3. beforeAll() called
4. tests run

So you can use `sc` in step 4 but not in step 2.